# Difference between in class and constructor initialisation

Tags: c#, c++, oop

I want to understand in the code below

```
class x
{
    int a=3;
    ...
    other class members
}

class y
{
    int a;
    public y()
    {
        a=3;
    }
    ...
    other class members
}
```

What is the difference between these two initialisation methods?
Also does it have anything to do with static classes?

Comment: Are you sure you're talking about C++? There is no thing as a static class in C++, member function visibility is not per-function, classes are terminated by a semicolon ...

Comment: Normally you initialize like `public y() : a(3) { }` instead. Alsop your indentation style originally was completely bizarre and impossible to read.

Comment: I see only one initialization method.

Comment: But the only semicolon was in the right place at least :-) @tadman

Comment: @ubik I'm sure the compiler was super excited about finding something it could recognize!

Comment: So class x variable 'a' cannot be defined like that, is it?

Comment: You code is not C++.  The C++ syntax is "`public:`", with a colon, ':', after the word "public".  C++ and C# are different languages.

Comment: Are you asking about C++ or C#.  they are two different languages.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews  As per my question that really doesn't matter. The coding was just enough to support what i was asking. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Its a lot easier to find faults than to find the answer to the real question in this world :)

Comment: @shrutiiyyer _"As per my question that really doesn't matter"_ It actually does matter. Refrain from tag spamming for unrelated language tags please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Under the C++11 standard, we can supply an **in-class initializer** for a
>   data member. When we create objects, the in-class initializers will be
>   used to initialize the data members. Members without an initializer
>   are default initialized.

Your first example uses an **in-class initializer**, while your second example only initializes `a` within the default constructor.

Say you have another constructor `z`, which takes some parameters but does not initialize data member `a`. Then upon calling `z`,

- If you use in-class initializer, it will be used to set `a = 3`.
- If you only initialize `a` in your default constructor, then `a` will be uninitialized.

Comment: Well Thank you so much for the 'Positive response'. And yes this sort of initialisation is possible in almost all OOP supporting languages. I got my answer on a different website. Just to let others know, the class x variable 'a' will be taking the value 3 if the constructor doesn't give it another value or if there's no constructor. If constructor gives it a value the '3' will be simply dumped.